# GTK - make widget settings persistant

Tags: gtk

I have a simple GTK program in c that requires the user to set values using GTK Scale widgets. Is there a way to make the settings persistent so that they will still be there when the program is closed and run again?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GSettings`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GSettings.html). Briefly, this involves writing a "settings schema" describing the pieces of data (each known as a "setting") that you want to save across program runs. Then, you can use `g_settings_bind()` to bind the setting to the `value` property of your `GtkScale`'s `GtkAdjustment`, so the value will automatically be saved each time the slider is dragged.